# Events declared in a class

Tags: actionscript-3

I sometimes see events declared near the top of the class (i.e. below the imports but above the constructor):

```
/**
* Description here
*
**/

[Event(name="complete", type="flash.events.Event")]
```

What exactly is this? Is this an "import" of a certain type of event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an as3 metadata tag. See more there: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=metadata_3.html

This particular tag is used to define valid event attributes in a MXML tag representing that class. The IDE will also use those to let you autocomplete.